# RVM failed writing to body

Tags: ruby, terminal, rvm

I am trying to install RVM on my Mac running the latest OS.

I first tried

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
Cannot open for reading: "stable"
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    181      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   181
100 15779  100 15779    0     0  11505      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 98618
(23) Failed writing body
```

I then tried dropping the `stable`

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 24 2013 18:58:47)
Argument missing after: "-s"
More info with: "vim -h"
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    148      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   148
100 15779  100 15779    0     0   7706      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:-- 30698
(23) Failed writing body
```

I have also tried the following

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Vim:    Warning: Input is not from a terminal
100   184  100   184    0     0    111      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   111
100 15779  100 15779    0     0   8689      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 8300k
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

Comment: looks like bash runs vim?

Answer (score 1):

How about `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash`?

The [installation page for RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) is essential reading.

Comment: I have read the RVM page. I ran this command and updated the answer with the output.